# retrieve data based on a condition

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have 2 tables, `TA` and `TB`:

```
TA
--------
id  name
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f

TB
--------
id  p_id  name
1   1     a
2   1     b
3   1     c
4   2     a
5   2     b
6   2     d
```

I need : if `p_id = 1` then :

```
id  name match
1   a    1 
2   b    1
3   c    1
4   d    0
5   e    0
6   f    0
```

If `p_id = 2` then :

```
id  name match
1   a    1 
2   b    1
3   c    0
4   d    1
5   e    0
6   f    0
```

Comment: Do you have multiple values in fields?

Comment: yes ... i mean ...for example one record in TA is 1 | a and other record is 2 | b....same in TB as well

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the data in tabular format? Can you see if it is like the [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d994/1)?

Comment: its same as you have mentioned in SQL-Fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to achieve this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ab87/1)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ta
( id INT NOT NULL, 
  name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
) ;


INSERT INTO ta
  (id, name)
VALUES
  (1, 'a'),
  (2, 'b'),
  (3, 'c'),
  (4, 'd'),
  (5, 'e'),
  (6, 'f') ;



CREATE TABLE TB
    (`id` int, `p_id` int, `name` varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO TB
    (`id`, `p_id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'a'),
    (2, 1, 'b'),
    (3, 1, 'c'),
    (4, 2, 'a'),
    (5, 2, 'b'),
    (6, 2, 'd')
;

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE test
(my_p_id INT)
BEGIN
  SELECT TA.id, TA.name,
         (IF(TB.name IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) AS `match`
    FROM TA
    LEFT JOIN TB
      ON TA.name = TB.name
     AND TB.p_id = my_p_id;

END;
```

**Query 1**:

```
CALL test(1);
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ab87/1/0)**:

```
| ID | NAME | MATCH |
|----|------|-------|
|  1 |    a |     1 |
|  2 |    b |     1 |
|  3 |    c |     1 |
|  4 |    d |     0 |
|  5 |    e |     0 |
|  6 |    f |     0 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
CALL test(2);
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ab87/1/1)**:

```
| ID | NAME | MATCH |
|----|------|-------|
|  1 |    a |     1 |
|  2 |    b |     1 |
|  3 |    c |     0 |
|  4 |    d |     1 |
|  5 |    e |     0 |
|  6 |    f |     0 |
```

The query of interest is wraped in the procedure `test`. That makes working with SQLFiddle a little easier. But you certainly can use the query outside of a procedure. However, pay attention to the fact that the comparison to the parameter value is part of the LEFT JOIN evaluation.

For more informations on JOINs check out my JOIN series here: http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/

That series is written about SQL Server. But most concepts and most of the syntax apply to MySQL as well.

Comment: Great Sebastian.

I was trying same query ,but i was unable to figure out 'ON' condition. thanks

Comment: nice reply @SebastianMeine :)